# How can I stop google.com from pulling my cursor away from the URL with Greasemonkey (or Adblock)?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, adblock

How can I stop google.com from pulling my cursor away from the URL and focusing it on the search box with Greasemonkey?

I use google as my home page and hit the home button to open a new tab, maybe not the best way to do it, but it is habit. I will start typing in a URL and when the page is done loading the Google search field pulls my cursor away when I'm half done typing.

I know a decent amount of javascript but I don't even know where to start when viewing Googles page source. If someone could write a script for this I would love you forever, and I'm sure many others would too!

EDIT:

Possibly the better question is how to do this with Adblock Plus?

EDIT#2:

Is it possible to run javascript before a specific page loads with a firefox plugin? Or, is it possible to block javascript on a page before it loads?

I am not looking for any "work arounds" I am looking for a fix. A fix to remove or disable "document.f.q.focus()".

Edit#3: What about a bookmarklet? Could it be possible with that?

Comment: There is a shortcut key `F6` that puts focus on the URL

Comment: @jball then how/why does it not do it when I turn off javascript?

Comment: `Ctrl-L` also works as a shortcut to move the focus up to the location bar.

Comment: Adblock Plus cannot help you with this.

Comment: @brock adams, just wondering, why?

Comment: @Dave: Adblock Plus cannot help because all it does is block external scripts, images, etc. from loading.  It cannot manipulate focus or chrome elements.    You could disable JavaScript, in all or in part, for Google using Adblock and/or NoScript, etc., and it still would not put focus where you need it.

Comment: `"What about a bookmarklet? Could it be possible with that?"`     No.  A bookmarklet has even less power than a GM script.  Besides, how would you activate it?  You'd have to press an icon or use a hotkey.  At that point, you're better off just pressing `Ctrl+L`.

Comment: You probably found a solution by now, but I still wanted to share... You may not be able to do it with greasemonkey, but you MAY be able to do it with javascript... in firefox you can create bookmarks that contain javascript... it may be possible that you could use javascript in the address for your homepage too...

Answer (score 2):

See http://noscript.net/

It's a firefox plugin that disables javascript on sites. You could configure it to just run on google.com, I think (if you do not want it to interfere with other sites).

Noscript is more secure, but it can be a pain because it uses a whitelist approach.

Or you can use [YesScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yesscript/), which operates a blacklist instead.

Re: `"I just want to blacklist a specific line of code on 1 site"`...
There is no addon to do that.  You can block all scripts from a site using ***NoScript*** or ***YesScript***.  Or you can block a specific JS *file* using ***Adblock***.

You cannot selectively block bits of JS that are embedded in the main page, except in rare occasions GM can *sometimes* work around it.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring noscript out. Can you point me in the right direction? Everything seems to be based on whitelisting, I just want to blacklist a specific line of code on 1 site.

Comment: @Dave: Updated the answer to also provide the blacklist add-on.

Comment: first, open "google.com", hover over the noscript icon and click "untrusted" --> "mark google.com as untrusted". Then hover the icon again and click "Allow scripts globally". This blocks google.com completely, though (not only one site or the mentioned line of code).

Comment: after looking at yesscript, it think it looks like a better approach for this than noscript, too.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like trying to use an anvil to smash an ant. Or some other, better, complex-tool-for-simple-job analogy. I would suggest either setting your home page to a blank page, or opening new tabs with a new tab button or Ctrl+T.

Comment: True, but I will have more fun smashing that ant with an anvil then I will with a penny. Also, I always love using big fancy tools for stupid little tasks, way more fun. I'm a man right?I wouldn't have asked this question if I wanted people to tell me to use a different method.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe it is possible, just looking around a bit. The focus actually comes from the onload attribute of the body element:

```
onload="document.f.q.focus();if(document.images)new Image().src='/images/srpr/nav_logo27.png'"
```

As you can see, `document.f.q.focus()` is your issue. However, I can't get a GM script to run before that `onload` is executed. I'm not too experienced with that particular issue, though: any GM scripts I've written are novelties whose load order doesn't matter a great deal, so long as it's done after the page is loaded.

If you know how to make GM scripts run before an `onload` (on a very light webpage), then it's as simple as saying `unsafeWindow.document.body.onload = null`.

Comment: Maybe I could make my own web page that has an iframe containing google.com, then set that as my home page?

Comment: @Dave: Well, you could also copy the Google source and remove the onload manually (or through scripting). If you're feeling particularly zealous, you could set up a cronjob to do that every so often to keep the source fresh.

Comment: hehehe, I like the way you think.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with Greasemonkey, because GM cannot manipulate chrome elements enough to set focus to the address bar.

You cannot do this with Adblock for the same reason, and because Adblock just stops external elements from loading.

None of the FF scripting add-ons could do this either, as far as I can tell.

You *could* write an extension/add-on to reset focus, but the real problem here is that the user is ignoring the tools in place for the job.

As Scott Cranfill said, use <kbd>Ctrl T</kbd> to open a new tab.

If a button is absolutely desired, Firefox already provides one. Do this:

1. In the Firefox menu, select *View* --> *Toolbars*  --> *Customize...* .
2. Find the "New Tab" icon [image] and drag it to your toolbar.
3. Click *that* icon, from now on, when you want a new blank tab.
4. Done!

Comment: I'm not trying to "set focus" I'm trying to stop google from running javascript. And what about noscript ff addon?

Comment: also, I'm not ignoring tools in place, I use ctrl-t all the time. I am hitting home to do a search and then remember where I wanted to go and start typing before the page has finished loading. Probably wouldn't happen as much if the page was cached, but I disable my cache for web development.

Comment: You said, "How can I stop google.com from pulling my cursor away from the URL and focusing it on the search box with Greasemonkey?"  The way the question is worded, focus is the heart of the problem.   NoScript, or YesScript, will block JS from Google.  But the focus will be in limbo, neither the address bar nor the search box will have it.  Also, Google (Grab-All) really needs JS to be much good these days.

Comment: `"I am hitting home to do a search and then remember where I wanted to go and start typing before the page has finished loading."`     Well, in that case, hit `Esc` to immediately stop the page from loading and resume typing your URL. (But you'll have to be very quick.)